# android 3G socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, 3g

I have successfully written that client/server java application, i also configured the port forwarding in my router, now i can perfectly send socket from any network over internet to my server, my problem is when i tried the client code in my android phone it works only in the same network with the server, but when i use 3g my server doesn't receive anything!
any help will be so appreciated.
here is the android code

```
      @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        Socket s = new Socket(ServerIp,6882);
                    /*  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeUTF("hello");
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();*/

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR WHILE SENDING THE SOCKET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            };
```

Comment: Firewall issue?  Who knows without further information.  Do you get an error of which you can provide the details?  Have you tried to test 3G connectivity from the device to your server some other way (e.g. Telent, a web browser, pinging etcetera)?

Comment: @J0e3gan its much more fun to just take a wild guess like me

Comment: What happens when you try? Is there anything in Logcat?

Answer (score -2):

You must add the [INTERNET permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```